# Create a Canonical URL with PHP

Tags: php, seo

I've a website which is created using PHP. It Contains so many Non-Canonical URL's.

**Example**

`http://example.com/page.php?id=10`

I just wanna make these kinda URL's into Canonical Form. I searched over Google and Found Solution. It says use link rel=canonical in head tag. It didn't make any changes in my `URL`. Can anyone tell me, how it works and how can I see that canonical URL is working. I'm new to SEO. Can anyone assist ?

Comment: in php you can do by using the link or by `get` request. if your method will be `GET` then this kind of URL can be achieved.

Comment: can u suggest me any example???

Comment: please share what you have done so far

Comment: I just added <link rel="canonical" href="<?php $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; echo $url;?>"> in head tag in my non-canonical file..

Comment: "Canonical"... You keep using that word, but I'm not sure it means what you think it means. Can you clarify what you think it means, please?

Comment: Adding `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` will make the canonical URL not work if you site has multiple domains names. You should hard code the one domain name, then all the other will be converted to it. For example: `<?php $url = "http://domainname{$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}"; echo "<link rel='canonical' href=$url>";?>`

Comment: Here is the easiest and correct way to do it: `<link rel='canonical' href="https://www.domainname.com<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" >` this will prevent google to have duplicate of you pages in search results. ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canonical and non-canonical URLs or pages have same content. Like on one non-canonical URL you are showing order records sorted by date and on another non-canonical URL you are showing same records sorted by price.

For you it is different thing but Google search engine consider these two pages as a same page and index only one page

Now what page will Google engine index. It depends on their algorithms but you can define

```
 <link rel="canonical" href="YOUR_URL_FOR_CANONICAL_PAGE"/>
```

on all non-canonical page to tell Google search engine to index the URL you provide in the link tag instead of this non-canonical page

Read further from following source
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en

Comment: will it make any changes in url???
how'll i know that canonical url is working for my webite???

Comment: No need to make change in URL. You can check the Google rank of your pages to find out which page is getting index or/and check organic traffic on your site

Comment: So, This'll not make any changes in URL of page. But it'll be indexed by google. Right???

Comment: Yeah, trick is to define the link tag that I specified in my answer. When Google search engine parse your any non-canonical page, it will found your link tag and it realize that the page should be ranked is the different one

Comment: Yeah bro, i've done with adding the <link rel='canonical' href="<?php $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; echo $url;?>">> in my head tag. When i print the url it prints in canonical format oly.. but while checking in google analytics still it shows the non-canonical url????

Comment: I think you should give it some time. May be it is not picked by Google web crawler yet. Google web crawler is schedule to run on fixed intervals. When Google crawler run and find your page, the index will be updated

Comment: Hope, It should work... Thanks for ur comments...

Comment: Sorry bro, even after adding those canonical links google analytics recognises that url as non-canonical url oly.. Any further helps???